# Unable to inject Spring State machine within test context (No qualifying bean of type JpaStateMachineRepository)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-statemachine

I'm writing a test case to inject an instance of my Spring State Machine and input some events but nothing so far has made it start the context properly

State Machine Config

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableStateMachineFactory(contextEvents = false)
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 @Slf4j
 public class StateMachineConfig
    extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<ExecutionStates, ExecutionEvents> {

   private final AbstractStateMachineMonitor stateMachineMonitor;

   private final StateMachineRuntimePersister<Events, States, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister;

@Override
public void configure(final StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<Events, States> config)
        throws
        Exception {
    config.withConfiguration()
            .listener(new StateMachineListenerAdapter<>());

    config.withMonitoring()
            .monitor(stateMachineMonitor);
    config.withPersistence()
            .runtimePersister(stateMachineRuntimePersister);
    super.configure(config);
}

   @Override
   public void configure(final StateMachineStateConfigurer<Events, States> states)
        throws
        Exception {
    states.withStates().initial(ExecutionStates.INITED, initialAction()).end(ExecutionStates.COMPLETED)
            .states(EnumSet.allOf(ExecutionStates.class));
}

@Override
public void configure(final StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<Events, States> transitions)
        throws
        Exception {
    transitions
            .withExternal()
            .source(ExecutionStates.INITED).target(ExecutionStates.COMPLETED)
            .event(ExecutionEvents.COMPLETE);
}
```

Persistence Config

```
@Configuration
public class StateMachinePersistenceConfiguration {

@Bean
public StateMachineRuntimePersister<Events, States, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister(
        final JpaStateMachineRepository jpaStateMachineRepository) {
    return new JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<>(jpaStateMachineRepository);
}
```

}

failing test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { StateMachineConfig.class, StateMachineMonitor.class,    StateMachinePersistenceConfiguration.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {StateMachinePersistenceConfiguration.class})
class Test {

@Autowired
private StateMachine<Events, States> machine;

@Test
public void testInitialState() throws Exception {
    StateMachineTestPlan<Events, States> plan =
            StateMachineTestPlanBuilder.<Events, States>builder()
            .defaultAwaitTime(2)
            .stateMachine(machine1)
            .step()
            .expectStateChanged(1)
            .expectStateEntered(Events.INIT)
            .and()
            .build();

    plan.test();
}
```

dependencies

- java 11
- spring boot 2.4.2 spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.4.2
- spring-statemachine-autoconfigure, starter-data-jpa, spring-statemachine-starter and spring-statemachine-test 2.4.0
- junit 5

any help would be appreciated